# Why is Kaine glowing with a green aura?

Tags: nier-replicant-1.22474487139

While hunting for Wolf Pelts in the Desert, I noticed at some point
Kainé had started glowing with a green aura. Nothing else about her seemed different aside from the green glow, and the aura went away after I exited the area.

Why was Kainé glowing with a green aura?

[image: Kaine glowing green]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She's been poisoned.

> Most likely caused by one of the scorpions hiding underground.

Comment: Does poison affect Kaine at all?

Comment: @Stevoisiak Hard to tell, I guess. NPCs fighting for you can't really die, they'll faint for a moment at best. I guess it does, but I can't remember ever seeing anyone "die" from it.